# "Links" on Privileges page should be actual HTML links

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks

On the [list of privileges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), each item links to a detailed explanation of the capabilities included in that privilege. These items are not actual links, so I can't (for example) right-click and Open Link in New Tab, Copy Link Location, or do anything else I would expect to be able to do on a link other than click on it. I don't see any reason why they they need to be like this.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see any good reason for these to be JavaScript links so I second your request.
I too like to open a series of items like that in tabs.  Old-fashioned links, please.